# How can I get data from spring controller by ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have an `ajax` on a `jsp` page which calls a spring controller through URL `/check` .

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/check",
    data : {
    "id" : ${articleCount}
    },
    success: function(data){
    //response from controller
    }
});
```

Now, the controller looks like,

```
@RequestMapping("/check")
public String check(@RequestParam Integer id, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
    boolean a = getSomeResult();
    if (a == true) {
        model.addAttribute("alreadySaved", true);
        return view;
    } else
        model.addAttribute("alreadySaved", false);

    return view;
}
```

I sent data using model and tried to access it in `success: function(data)` as `"${alreadySaved}"`but it shows blank.

Is there any way I can receive that `true/false` data on the view page?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to add the @ResponseBody annotation for spring ajax calls example

```
@RequestMapping("/check")     
@ResponseBody
public String check(@RequestParam Integer id, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
    boolean a = getSomeResult();
    if (a == true) {
        model.addAttribute("alreadySaved", true);
        return view;
    } else {
        model.addAttribute("alreadySaved", false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay. How can I get that response on the view side?

Comment: that means view is empty.please return the model object as response.

Comment: No, the view is not empty. The view is injected by spring from springmvc servlet. It is a string that resolves to load a JSP.

Comment: I had some misconception. I got it right now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

use `@ResponseBody`

Spring will bind the return value to outgoing HTTP response body when you add `@ResponseBody` annotation.

```
@ResponseBody
public String check(@RequestParam Integer id, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
    boolean a = getSomeResult();
    if (a == true) {
        return "already saved";
    } 
    return "error exist";
}
```

Spring will use HTTP Message converters to convert the return value to HTTP response body [serialize the object to response body], based on Content-Type used in request HTTP header.

for more info:

http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-requestbody-responsebody-example/

Answer (score 1):

Controller part

You have to add the @ResponseBody annotation for spring ajax calls example

View Part

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/check",
    data : {
        "id" : ${articleCount}
    },
    success: function(data){
        $('#input_field').val(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to return the values from the ajax request , you should use the `@ResponseBody` annotation . As your method return type is `String` make sure you return the string value and not your view to the jsp.

Since it will render the jsp again the response

```
@ResponseBody
public String check(@RequestParam Integer id, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
    boolean a = getSomeResult();
    if (a == true) {
        return "already saved";
    } 
    return "error exist";
}
```

And in your jsp,

```
success: function(data){
    alert(data);
}
```

Comment: But I need to return view from that method because without that, spring will not be able to load the jsp.

Comment: @najus No the concept of ajax is to refresh the part of the page so it is enough to the send the return value alone . As you are loading the same page