# In Spring Boot ,During click event Html Page Redirect and Loading the values in Dropdown components using Jquery /Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using STS 3.9.0 Tool, my project is based on Spring Boot, Thymeleaf, MySQL, Html-Bootstrap and JQuery.

In Spring Boot, during a click event the Html page needs to redirect to another page and load the dynamically generated values in Dropdown components using Jquery or Thymeleaf.

**Explanation**

HTML click event to call `@Controller` to redirecting another Html page:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getflat", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String propertyRegistration() {
    return "FlatReg";
}
```

The URL will Be `localhost:8080/getflat` It will rediect to FlatReg.html, which is located in template folder.

and during load time, again hit `@RestController` URL to fetch the data from the DB and Load the data to Dropdown Controller

```
@PostMapping("/flatreg/saveflat")
public ResponseMsg doSaveFlatDetails() {
    ResponseMsg responseMsg = new ResponseMsg();
    try {
        // My DB call Goes Here
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return responseMsg;
}
```

`ResponseMsg` class Like

```
public class ResponseMsg {

    private String status;
    private Object dataObj;

    public ResponseMsg() {

    }

    public ResponseMsg(String status, Object dataObj) {
        super();
        this.status = status;
        this.dataObj = dataObj;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Object getDataObj() {
        return dataObj;
    }

    public void setDataObj(Object dataObj) {
        this.dataObj = dataObj;
    }
}
```

I don't know how to achieve this. Is there any other way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: i still not able to achive ..so please any one give some ideas...

Comment: @Kamuran Sonecek in JQuery is possible to achive using onLoad(),but i dont know how to i place the list of values into Dropdown components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to achieve this.

1. Before rendering the page from the Controller method `propertyRegistration()`,  add all the data you need to display in the page `FlatReg` page like so.

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/getflat", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView propertyRegistration() {
       ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("FlatReg");
       modelAndView.addObject("data", service.getData()); //Get data from your service layer and set it in the ModelAndView to be later retreived in your FlatReg page.
       return "FlatReg";
   }
   ```
2. The second way would be to load the "FlatReg" page as you are doing right now and then using `Ajax` call your Controller method `doSaveFlatDetails` to get the required data. Check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795027/how-can-i-get-data-from-spring-controller-by-ajax) link on how to make an ajax call.

Hope this helps.

Comment: how do i make page redirection in in controller page?

Comment: `return "redirect:/YOUR_MAPPED_URL"` where `YOUR_MAPPED_URL` is a url that is mapped by any of your controller method using `@Requestmapping`. Also please accept and upvote the answer if it has helped you in any way. Thanks

Comment: sure buddy i will try it...if succedded i will give upvote...Thanks for helping

Comment: return new ModelAndView("redirect:/FlatReg"); --- page 404 file not found error

Comment: Do you have a method annotated with `@Requestmapping('/FlatReg')`? `/FlatReg` should be mapped by any method in you Controller class.

Comment: i changed the code" ModelAndView flatRegWebData = new ModelAndView("FlatReg");   return flatRegWebData; ",so it will redirected to respective page,Now i want know how to i get the data in dropdown...using Thymeleaf..Thanks in advance buddy...