# Can't Access Model Attributes After AJAX GET Request

Tags: ajax, spring-boot, jsp, model-view-controller

I have a Spring boot controller which I want to accept as an optional parameter a String of the div clicked such that I can load my JSP accordingly with JSTL. My problem is that after AJAX passes the parameter to the controller, it sets the attribute in the model however I cannot access the model attribute in my JSP.

My controller:

```
@GetMapping("/MainMenu")
    public String index(Model model, Principal principal, @RequestParam(required = false) String linkClicked){
        if(linkClicked != null){
            logger.info("link clicked");
            model.addAttribute("linkClicked", linkClicked);
        }
        return "MainMenu";
    }
```

AJAX:

```
$(document).on("click", "#frameworkLink", function () {
    var linkClicked = $(this).text();
    $(".groups").detach();
    $(".frameworks").show();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/MainMenu",
        data: {"linkClicked": linkClicked},
        dataType: 'text',
    });
});
```

JSP:

```
<c:if test="${linkClicked != null}">
                <c:if test="${linkClicked == 'Frameworks'}">
                    <div class="frameworks">
                        <sec:authorize access="hasAuthority('Admin')">
                            <button class="createGroup" id="createFramework" type="button" onclick="createFramework()">Create Framework</button>
                        </sec:authorize>
                        <c:forEach items="${frameworkList}" var="framework">
                            <div class="framework">${framework}</div>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </div>
                </c:if>
            </c:if>
```

EDIT: Adding `@ResponseBody` to my controller method as suggested by the duplicate post made no difference. Additionally, I tried changing the return value of the controller to `ModelAndView` which also made no difference.

Comment: When you use ajax the response from the server is return back to success function of ajax you can access that value under success function . Also , refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795027/how-can-i-get-data-from-spring-controller-by-ajax) post will help you to understand better .

Comment: In the case that I want to access the model should I be returning a ModelAndView? In which case how would I make that available to the JSP from AJAX?